# Flyway validate failed:detected resolved migration not applied to database

Tags: flyway

I have created two migration SQL files for my Java web application: V1 and V2.

Upon the first start of the application, everything looks and works fine. Here's what I'm seeing in the log:

```
23-Aug-2020 09:31:35.923 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.info Current version of schema `cloudregs`: << Empty Schema >>
23-Aug-2020 09:31:36.074 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.info Migrating schema `cloudregs` to version 1 - initial
23-Aug-2020 09:31:36.118 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.warn DB: Changing sql mode 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' is deprecated. It will be removed in a future release. (SQL State: HY000 - Error Code: 3090)
23-Aug-2020 09:31:37.312 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.warn DB: Changing sql mode 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' is deprecated. It will be removed in a future release. (SQL State: HY000 - Error Code: 3090)
23-Aug-2020 09:31:37.419 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.info Migrating schema `cloudregs` to version 2 - user-invite
23-Aug-2020 09:31:37.459 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.warn DB: Changing sql mode 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' is deprecated. It will be removed in a future release. (SQL State: HY000 - Error Code: 3090)
23-Aug-2020 09:31:40.742 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.warn DB: Changing sql mode 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' is deprecated. It will be removed in a future release. (SQL State: HY000 - Error Code: 3090)
23-Aug-2020 09:31:40.812 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.info Successfully applied 2 migrations to schema `cloudregs` (execution time 00:04.912s)
```

And here's the corresponding `flyway_schema_history`:

```
+----------------+---------+-------------+------+---------------------+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+
| installed_rank | version | description | type | script              | checksum | installed_by | installed_on        | execution_time | success |
+----------------+---------+-------------+------+---------------------+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+
|              2 | 2       | user-invite | SQL  | V2__user-invite.sql | 39331208 | root         | 2020-08-23 09:31:40 |           3343 |       1 |
+----------------+---------+-------------+------+---------------------+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+
```

It looks that only the second migration has been saved to `flyway_schema_history`.

When re-starting the application, I'm getting the following error:

```
Validate failed:
Detected resolved migration not applied to database: 1
```

What am I missing?

**Edit**: the issue seems to be fixed by upgrading from Flyway version 6.4.2 to 6.5.5